# write a struct in binary in c++

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I have the need of writing the data contained in a struct to a binary file.

Lets say given the struct of

```
struct data {
unsigned char sig;
int reserved;
}
```

I want to be able to simply output the contents of this struct to a file.

I have tried to use this

```
fstream out("C:\\somepath", ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);
data writedata;
writedata.sig = 'BM';
writedata.reserved = NULL;
out.write((char*)&writedata, sizeof(writedata));
out.close();
```

I expected the output would be (in hex, using a 32 bit compiler(so ints are 4 bytes)):

```
42 4D 00 00 00 00
```

But this is not what is printed.

Can someone explain why this is not working and the steps necessary to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: you assigned `'BM'` to sig which is unsigned char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `'BM'` is two bytes, and cannot be fit into a single `unsigned char` (`'BM'` is probably treated by your compiler as a multibyte literal, which is probably not what you want).

Then, the compiler is free to add padding inside a structure to align it to the correct word boundaries; on x86 correct members aligment guarantees much better read performances, on other architectures if the alignment is wrong you get a hardware exception.

In your case, for example, on 32-bit x86 the binary layout of your struct will be one byte of `sig`, three bytes of padding, and then the `reserved` `int` (that will be aligned on 4-byte boundaries for optimal access speed).

There's no standard way to avoid padding; you have to resort to compiler-specific tricks. On VC++, you'll have to use `#pragma pack`, supported also on g++ and clang, although their "native" way is to use `__attribute__(packed)`.

By the way, if you have to write a "portable" file format to file (like the DIB you are trying to write) always use fixed-size integer types (from `stdint.h`) and be ready to deal with endianness issues if you plan to port to other architectures.

Comment: I'm not worried about portability issues right now, this is just a little pet project of mine to get accustomed to working with raw image files. The example I gave isn't the full BMP headers of course, it would get redundant. Let me try something to see what you are saying.

Comment: I am now trying this **char* sig = "BM";** and this works fine when I write it with **out.write()**, but even with **#pragma pack(2)** it still packs two bytes on the end. Suggestions?

Comment: If you write `char * sig="BM"` you are embedding a pointer in your structure, so when writing it on file you'll output the address of that string. What you want is to embed a `char[2]'. Also, you want `#pragma pack(1)` if you want to have no padding at all.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler errors/warnings that I see:

1. Missing `;` at the end of the definition of `data`.
2. Assinging `'BM'` is wrong. It needs to be single character.
3. Assigning `NULL` to `data.reserved`. You should make it:

   ```
   data.reserved = 0;
   ```

If you want to minimize the space taken by the file on disk, write each field of the struct separately.

```
out.write((char*)&writedata.sig, sizeof(writedata.sig));
out.write((char*)&writedata.reserved, sizeof(writedata.reserved));
```

Another thing I noticed is that you are opening your file with the flag `ios::app`. It appends to an existing file. Is that what you mean? If not, you can remove that flag.